# Battery not charging but detected

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

my Lenovo N581 detects the battery, but it doesn't charge it (as soon as I unplug the AC, it turns off).

When i type `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` into the terminal I get:

```
native-path:          BAT1
vendor:               LENOVO
  model:                PABAS0241231
  serial:               41167
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              So 01 Jul 2018 14:48:33 CEST (59 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         0 Wh
    energy-full-design:  0 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

What I tried:

- buy a new battery
- reset the cmos battery (unplug; remove battery; press power for 30 seconds)
- appears on windows (8, 10) and ubuntu (16, 18)

Does anyone have an Idea what to do next? 
Do I have to buy a new mainboard?

Thanks for helping!!

Comment: You have done everything I would have done.  There is a very big possibility that the charging circuit could be bad on the motherboard.

Comment: Do you know how I could fix this without buying a new mainboard? Is this possible?

Comment: I am not aware of any software settings that can cause a system to not want to charge a battery when it is plugged into the charger.  I guess you could try another charger for the unit as it might be bad.  Unlikely though if the system runs fine with the charger plugged in but it is still a possibility.   If the motherboard is bad, then if you were good at soldering and reading schematics and find them online, then you could fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your question. I tried all steps from all the answers and at some point it worked again but I cannot figure out which answer was the helpful one.

Answer (score 35):

The following steps fixed my battery charging on a Carbon X1 5th gen. Your BIOS might be a bit different, but the principle might be the same:

- shut down notebook
- go to BIOS (to enter the BIOS, I pressed ENTER at boot, and then F1)
- in the BIOS, go to `Config`, then selecte `Disable Built-in Battery`. This disables the battery completely (i.e. disconnects the battery circuit logically)
- unplug the charger
- press the power button for about 10 seconds
- plug the charger back in
- boot up

Now my notebook is charging again.

Comment: Wow thanks for answering!! I will try it ASAP and tell if it worked!! Thanks again!

Comment: Worked for me on a Lenovo P52s. Thanks!

Comment: T580: the first time it didn't work. I ran the same steps again after removing TLP Thinkpad battery settings now battery charging indicator is working. Thank you!

Comment: Worked on Lenovo X1-Extreme after installing Arch and having battery issues. Thank you!

Comment: Worked very well for me too (Lenovo L390). Thanks!

Comment: My old Lenovo Thinkpad 01962 CS did not have this option...

Comment: Worked also for me (Lenovo T15)! Thank you!

Comment: Work for me too.. Amaz.. Still dont know why this happened...

Comment: Yes, worked for me too! Thinkpad T460s here.

Comment: Thinkpad X230 does not have this option in BIOS. I removed the battery physically, but that does not seem to have fixed the issue. (Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: Thanks Man , This works for me as well, Lenovo ThinkPad-L14

Comment: Worked for my Lenovo P1! Thanks

Comment: Does not work for me on T14s Gen 3 Intel. I've also tried BIOS update,  Laptop charges if powered off completely. When on, it recognizes it is plugged in, and does not discharge battery, but says "Not charging".  Maybe there's a setting somewhere to not charge above some threshold level (battery currently at 94%)?? Will try discharging further I guess

Comment: This did not work for me on a Thinkpad X1 Gen 9 (in March 2023). Laptop powered off spontaneously at 95% battery and works when plugged in, but turns off when disconnected. Battery neither discharges nor charges. upower output is similar to @gxor's. I've run your (@BenediktKöppel) procedure and this behavior continues. I haven't gotten a screwdriver and tried manually removing the battery yet

Comment: addendum (possibly irrelevant): This happened during a system update, which I guess is why they say to keep the device plugged in for those. I imagine the system is at too high a level to mess up the battery, but just in case this information could be diagnostically useful in the future...

Comment: Also worked for my Ideapad Flex 5, thanks! Charge rate prior to this fix was ~4W, then skyrocketed to ~40W (nominal charge: 65W). Out of curiosity, what does this 10sec button push accomplish?

Comment: Worked on my Lenovo X1 as well.

Comment: Dark magic! It worked on my x1 yoga 3rd generation. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Run this command to refresh upower and show the charging battery icon.

busctl call --system org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 org.freedesktop.UPower.Device Refresh

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I dont know what is the issue. Now the battery indicator is updating after this command.

Comment: Thanks! This works.

Answer (score 3):

For me worked truncated version of [Benedikt solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099877/1603216)

- shut down notebook
- unplug the charger
- press the power button for about 10 seconds
- boot up
- plug the charger back in

The last two steps' positions changed compared to the original.

Comment: Worked for me: ThinkPad P14s, Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

For Lenovo Thinkpad T460 what fixed this for me was

1. Remove the AC adapter
2. Put a paperclip in the emergency reset hole in the bottom of the laptop and held it for about 30 seconds.
3. Started the laptop without AC adapter plugged in
4. Then plugged in the AC adapter

And then the battery started charging again. Not sure if #3 and #4 made a difference but those are the steps I took

Comment: Similar with HP x360 1040: turn off, keep pressing Power Button for ~10 seconds until it blinks (= reset). Turn it on again, and it works

Answer (score 0):

My system, Lenovo Yoga, didn't have the BIOS setting for battery mentioned in the answer  [above](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099877/1121280).  What fixed the problem for me was loading Ubuntu in Recovery Mode (from "Advanced Setting for Ubuntu" from grub boot loader) and rebooting.