# Laptop battery toggles between not charging (0%) and fully charged (100%)

Tags: 22.04, battery, thinkpad

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad W520 and Ubuntu 22.04. By mistake it got to 0% and now it shuts down whenever the charger is plugged off, thus I can only work with it plugged in. In addition, the battery toggles between not charging (0%) and fully charged (100%). when typing

> upower -i `upower -e | grep 'BAT'`

that's what i get [when it's fully charged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x00D4.png) and [when it's not charging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlrWm.png).

I've tried the solutions from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051209/battery-not-charging-but-detected), but my BIOS doesn't have the option of disabling the built-in battery and the restarting operations didn't work.

Should I buy a new battery?

Comment: Thinkpad W520 has a removable battery pack. It does not make sense to have a bios option to disable the battery.

Comment: You can try doing a power reset.  Most systems support this.  You remove all power sources, even the battery if it is removable, press and hold down the power button for about 30 seconds.  Then put the power supply and battery back in, then power it back on.

Comment: @Terrance, I've already tried it, didn't work.

Comment: If the charging circuit isn't bad in the laptop, then it could be a bad battery.  Some cheap batteries out there do not like dropping below a certain charge or they will never recharge again.